# @RequestBody is fetching null values

Tags: json, spring-boot, http, request-mapping

```
@PostMapping("/req")
public String message_handler(@RequestBody messageStructure ingress_req_msg) {

        System.out.println("Inside message_handler");
        System.out.println(ingress_req_msg); // always print null
        return "Welcome";
}

class messageStructure 
{
String MsgData;
//getters and setters are there

//Constructor
public messageStructure(messageStructure req)
{
    Msgdata = req.getMsgdata();
}

}


Postman Request Syntax:
{
    "MsgData":"Sample Message Data",
}
```

1. Tried to check dependencies.
2. Refreshed gradle dependencies.
3. Rechecked class variable Names messageStructure
4. Set the same json content values
   { "MsgData":"example.test.co"}

Comment: And without knowing what you send and what your `messageStructure` (weird naming convention but alas) looks like we should be able to answer this?

Comment: Just post your data and your class `messageStructure`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you imported the right `@RequestBody` annotation:

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
```

Comment: That i have already checked